# Go big.Int factorial with recursion

Tags: go

I am trying to implement this bit of code:

```
func factorial(x int) (result int) {
  if x == 0 {
    result = 1;
  } else {
    result = x * factorial(x - 1);
  }
  return;
}
```

as a big.Int so as to make it effective for larger values of x.

The following is returning a value of 0 for     fmt.Println(factorial(r))

The factorial of 7 should be 5040?

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "math/big"

func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    //n := big.NewInt(40)
    r := big.NewInt(7)

    fmt.Println(factorial(r))

}

func factorial(n *big.Int) (result *big.Int) {
    //fmt.Println("n = ", n)
    b := big.NewInt(0)
    c := big.NewInt(1)

    if n.Cmp(b) == -1 {
        result = big.NewInt(1)
    }
    if n.Cmp(b) == 0 {
        result = big.NewInt(1)
    } else {
        // return n * factorial(n - 1);
        fmt.Println("n = ", n)
        result = n.Mul(n, factorial(n.Sub(n, c)))
    }
    return result
}
```

This code on go playground: http://play.golang.org/p/yNlioSdxi4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `int` version, every `int` is distinct. But in your `big.Int` version, you're actually sharing `big.Int` values. So when you say

```
result = n.Mul(n, factorial(n.Sub(n, c)))
```

The expression `n.Sub(n, c)` actually stores `0` back into `n`, so when `n.Mul(n, ...)` is evaluated, you're basically doing `0 * 1` and you get back `0` as a result.

Remember, the results of `big.Int` operations don't just return their value, they also store them into the receiver. This is why you see repetition in expressions like `n.Mul(n, c)`, e.g. why it takes `n` again as the first parameter. Because you could also say`result.Mul(n, c)` and you'd get the same value back, but it would be stored in `result` instead of `n`.

Here is your code rewritten to avoid this problem:

```
func factorial(n *big.Int) (result *big.Int) {
    //fmt.Println("n = ", n)
    b := big.NewInt(0)
    c := big.NewInt(1)

    if n.Cmp(b) == -1 {
        result = big.NewInt(1)
    }
    if n.Cmp(b) == 0 {
        result = big.NewInt(1)
    } else {
        // return n * factorial(n - 1);
        fmt.Println("n = ", n)
        result = new(big.Int)
        result.Set(n)
        result.Mul(result, factorial(n.Sub(n, c)))
    }
    return
}
```

And here is a slightly more cleaned-up/optimized version (I tried to remove extraneous allocations of `big.Int`s): http://play.golang.org/p/feacvk4P4O

Comment: Thank You! Yes those results of big.Int operations do get a little bit tricky.

Comment: @Greg: Here is a [much more compact](http://play.golang.org/p/fesr8ZINYu) implication that skips recursion and goes straight for a for loop instead.

Answer (score 16):

Go package `math.big` has `func (*Int) MulRange(a, b int64)`. When called with the first parameter set to 1, it will return b!:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    x := new(big.Int)
    x.MulRange(1, 10)
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Will produce

> 3628800

Comment: That is `x.MulRange`, not `x.mulRange`.

Comment: Underrated answer here.   Most usages probably don't need a big.Int as the input to a factorial method, only as a return type (because only the answer is very large).  If that is the case, MulRange is much simpler (and faster).

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func factorial(x *big.Int) *big.Int {
    n := big.NewInt(1)
    if x.Cmp(big.NewInt(0)) == 0 {
        return n
    }
    return n.Mul(x, factorial(n.Sub(x, n)))
}

func main() {
    r := big.NewInt(7)
    fmt.Println(factorial(r))
}
```

Output:

```
5040
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-recursive version:

```
func FactorialBig(n uint64) (r *big.Int) {
    //fmt.Println("n = ", n)
    one, bn := big.NewInt(1), new(big.Int).SetUint64(n)
    r = big.NewInt(1)
    if bn.Cmp(one) <= 0 {
        return
    }
    for i := big.NewInt(2); i.Cmp(bn) <= 0; i.Add(i, one) {
        r.Mul(r, i)
    }
    return
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/91KD70ZJG_)